# Karaf Modules using Hibernate and Annotated Classes in External Package Get Wires Crossed

Tags: hibernate, deployment, persistence, bundle, karaf

*Is there a way to have multiple persistence bundles, deployed at the same time, that work on managing different hibernate annotated Java classes that are in the same external package/library?*

I have a working solution to use Hibernate within Karaf to manage persisting data defined in an annotated Java class. The solution includes three .kar files, one for managing persistence and two for a REST interface.

I updated the persistence module to point to annotated classes that are outside the module in a different library that is under my control.  Everything still works fine.

I created a second set of modules to manage a different data item.  Both data items are in the same library in the same package. In order to get either to work I had to include the package in the exported packages in the created persistence Kar file using bnd.  I found that I can deploy the kar files for either data item, but not both at the same time. Including the package containing the hibernate files in the Kar files "exported packages" doesn't seem to make sense anymore.  I had no success attempting to include them in the Import-Package definition and including an additional feature/bundle dependency on the external library.

Given that I have bundles to persist A and B, when the three .kar files for A are deployed all is ok.  When I deploy the .kar files for B, now persistence bundle A has been updated and it imports the persistence bundle B. Persistence bundle B imports A's persistence package. There appears to be cross dependencies between these solutions that I wish was not there.  Is there any way to separate the two?